# Using Crystal Reports with Azure in VB2010, Blank screen when run locally

Tags: asp.net, azure, crystal-reports, azure-sql-database

I have created an new Windows Azure Project, I can connect to my SQL Azure database to view data on a ListView.  I added a Crystal Report Viewer to an .aspx page and I can see the data inside VS2010. When I try and run it through VS I get a blank screen!  I have tried to create a report in the same way using a blank web site and a standard windows project and they both run fine.  Am I missing something obvious!

Comment: did you deploy crystal report runtime on azure VM?

Comment: I am not using a VM, I am creating a cloud service

Comment: however, there will be a backing VM for the cloudservice which you can access using RDP

Comment: I haven't set any VM's up, I only have a Cloud Service and SQL Database.

Comment: Open azure mgmt portal and select cloud service; Go to "Configure' Tab and look at bottom toolbar; You can select "Remote" button to set up RDP

Comment: I don't have a supported SDK for that.  I am trying to debug the service through visual studio - thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do it. I have done it myself by following [step by step blog post about running Crystal Reports on Azure](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html).

It revolves around creating a start up task to run a crystal reports installation file on your new Azure web role instances. There are plenty of snags which I have listed so give it a try. It does work!